# TFS Branching/Release Strategy

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

I have a branching strategy in TFS 2015 that consists of Main and Dev. I need to setup a new build definition to continuously integrate/release to upper environments (DEV, UAT, PROD).

Does it make sense to configure the definition pointed to Main, or create a new folder to stage the releases and point the definition to this new folder?

I.e. A new dev branch is created off Main, updates and made and then a new branch is made in the staging folder to release. After the release, changes are merged back to Main.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC? Good branching strategies are wildly different between the two.

Comment: @DanielMann TFVC

Comment: Generally we will configure the definition pointed to Main, as Main is the relatively stable version of sources which merged from other branchs. But for testing you can create branches based on your requirements.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT What happens when you are working on a development branch, it's ready for testing so you merge to Main, build/release, then part way through the test cycle you have to do a hot-fix on the previous release? Do you rollback Main, make the change, then re-merge from the development branch?

Comment: @user2966445 Just as I mentioned: for testing you can create branches based on your requirements. Yeah, you can create a Test/Dev branch for testing until the project is stable enough, then merge the source to Main. For the hot-fix you can do it on these Test/Dev branches.